# Meta.SU seems to be broken.... in multiple ways

Tags: bug, asking-questions, per-site-meta, superuser

I was originally going to post about an *unrelated* bug

The posting page on MSU telling me I have no title or tags and not letting me do so.

> [image].

I've tried changing the title, and adding more tags. I'm a little stumped.

I'm currently on firefox 29.0 (with adblock plus and oneliner installed). My ISP runs a IPV6/IPV4 dualstack through IPV6rd if that's relevant.

Comment: I can [reproduce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/62JoV.png) on FF 27.0.1, IPv4-only. Also running ABP, though it's disabled on this site. Note that this occurs even without pressing the submit button - it's enough to enter and leave a field. I've heard that SU was recently moved onto CloudFlare - so possibly relevant is that @JourneymanGeek is in Singapore and I'm in Australia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, it's an issue with CloudFlare. Happened on SU proper yesterday as well.

We disabled in on Meta SU now and will continue to investigate.

Comment: Is [the editing of moderator election nominations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230785/suspicious-request-when-editing-nomination) affected too?