# Suspicious Request when editing Nomination

Tags: support, election, error-message, superuser, nominations

I am trying to edit my nomination on the [Super User Election](https://superuser.com/election?cb=1), but every time I submit, I get a `Suspicious Request`, as below:

> Suspicious request
>   Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Super User, please return to the previous page and try again.

I tried clearing my browser cache, flushing my caching proxy on our network (after hours, don't worry!), and even rebooting my system, but it does not go away! I can still vote up or down, or edit questions on the main site. This has been happening since around 2300 hrs UTC, yesterday.

Comment: More [Super User problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230751/meta-su-seems-to-be-broken-in-multiple-ways).

Comment: I just edited mine without an error. Strange.

Comment: Hmm, I'd better remove my vote for you... you're clearly suspicious! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fixed now... For some weird reason.

Thanks, whoever did it!